# How to embed html5 webpage in flex

Tags: apache-flex, embed, html

Using flex mx HTML component we can preview the website at AIR, however it seems did not support all features(audio,video) of html5. such as the following example:

```
<mx:HTML location="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_bear" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

when you running application, the video can not be displayed in AIR  windows.

Comment: I believe everything you write is correct!  Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video/Audio HTML5 tags are currently disabled in AIR.
[Here's](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/articles/air_and_webkit.html) article about items that are and aren't supported in AIR right now.